# Escape the current file name "{}" of shell find -exec in the subcommand result "$()"?

Tags: sh

I want to run something like:

```
find . -type files -exec echo "touch -cmd '"$(date --utc -r '{}' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N +0000")"' "$(ls --quoting-style=shell '{}')
```

It doesn't seem to work since "{}" doesn't seem to be expanded in the $(). How could I do to make it work right?

Comment: The command substitution is evaluated *before* `find` is run. It's not clear what you are actually trying to do, which makes it hard to  suggest the correct fix.

Comment: I'm trying to search for all files in the directory and generate a list of `touch -cmd <the file's date> <the file>`. Of course the output is likely to be redirected to a script file.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your problem.

Write a shell script, and then get the shell script working. Then execute your shell script using find.

find . -type files -exec myScript '{}'